# SQL - Is there a way to detect whether a value is not present in the column grouped over values from other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, db2

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name              Toys present

A1     ------      Dinosaur-1        
A1     ------      Dinosaur-2        
A1     ------      Dinosaur-3   
A1     ------      Dinosaur-1    
A1     ------      Dinosaur-5    
A2     ------      Dinosaur-1       
A2     ------      Dinosaur-2      
A2     ------      Dinosaur-3     
A3     ------      Dinosaur-2     
A3     ------      Dinosaur-2    
A3     ------      Dinosaur-2    
A4     ------      Dinosaur-3    
A4     ------      Dinosaur-3    
A5     ------      Dinosaur-1    
A5     ------      Dinosaur-1    
A5     ------      Dinosaur-1
```

Is there a value to return Names that don't have any 'Dinosaur-1' toys with them? 
In the above example, that would be 'A3' and 'A4'. I am having a hard time filtering out whether a name which could have multiple toys has this particular toy or have. I've tried Group By and Having clauses and also played around with CTEs but to no luck.

Please advise and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `name` and filter on groups that have no `toy` called `'Dinosaur-1'`, like so:

```
select name
from mytable
group by name
having max(toy = 'Dinosaur-1') = 0
```

Expression `toy = 'Dinosaur-1'`, when evaluated by MySQL in numeric context, returns `0` for false and `1` for true; so a maximum value of `0` indicates that no row in the group satisfies the condition.

Note: if you are running DB2 (which you tagged too), you can change the `having` clause to:

```
having max(case when toy = 'Dinosaur-1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```